# use of views for validation of an incorrect login-id or an unidentified user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, view

I read this on msdn:

Views let different users to see data in different ways, even when they are using the same 
data at the same time. This is especially useful when users who have many different interests and skill levels share the same database.

For example, a view can be created that retrieves only the data for the customers with whom an account manager deals. The view can determine which data to retrieve based on the login ID of the account manager who uses the view.

My question:

For the above example , i would have to have a column named Userid/LoginId on my table on which the view is created so that i can apply a check option in the view for this column. and then if a user with a name not in that column tries to enter data , then he/she is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You should

- add a column with the user's login or database user name (say you call it username),
- each row should have username populated with the login or database name of the person who is allowed to see that row
- you can then build a view where you use the builtin functions `SUSER_SNAME()` (for logins) or `USER_NAME` (for database names) in your WHERE clause to filter only the rows the user is allowed to see

See [Granting Row-Level Permissions in SQL Server (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076.aspx).

Comment: @paolo: i would have to add the legal users from beforehand, isn't it?

Comment: @sqlchild yes you would have to write the legal users in the DB before using this.

Comment: @paolo: i would have to add the legal users into the column in the table.

Comment: @sqlchild: How many users can see each row? If you have one and only one user who can see each row, you can add the username for that user in a column of the same table. But you have more than one user who can see each row, you should make this a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: @paolo: one row can be seen by multiple users. how to implement one to many relationship. can you help me with the code

Comment: @paolo: do i have to repeat the rows?

Comment: @sqlchild can you describe what you're trying to do? Your question was very specific on row-level security, but this type of thing is rarely used in practice. Do you have users running sql queries directly on your DB, each with their own database user? Often there's an application that accesses data and presents to the final users and most of the security is done at the application's level, not directly on the db. Can you expand a little on your specific problem and the architecture you're building/working with?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to add a column to the table: it could be more appropriate to instead add a new table to model the relationship.

There's a deisgn rule of thumb that states a table should model an entity or a relationship but not both. Let's say the table in question models the companies a customer owns (i.e. an entity table) and the business rule states the the account manager can only see companies relating to customers he looks after.

Is `account manager` an attribute of a `company`? No, so `account_manager` should not be a column (attribute) in the `Companies` table.

Is there a *direct* relationship between `account_manager` and a `company`? No, so a relationship table between is not due here (because the relationship is indirect).

Rather, the direct relationships are between `account manager` and `customer`, and between `customer` and `company` respectively. There should be two tables whose sole purpose is to model these relationships.